# Pic programming Using C counter up and down

Tags: c, pic, lcd

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "LCD.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int a; int x = 0; char s[10000];
    TRISD = 0x00; TRISB = 0x03;
    Lcd_Start();
    while(1)
    {
        Lcd_Clear();Lcd_Set_Cursor(1,1);
        int x = 0;
        if (PORTBbits.RB0==1)
        {
            Lcd_Clear();
            x += 1;
            Lcd_Print_String("Current Number");
            Lcd_Set_Cursor(2,1);
           Lcd_Print_String(x)
        }
        else if(PORTBbits.RB1==1)
        {
            Lcd_Clear();
            x += -1;
            Lcd_Print_String("Current Number");
            Lcd_Set_Cursor(2,1);
            Lcd_Print_String(x);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is `Lcd_Print_String`:

```
void Lcd_Print_Char(char data)  //Send 8-bits through 4-bit mode
{
    char Lower_Nibble,Upper_Nibble;
    Lower_Nibble = data&0x0F;
    Upper_Nibble = data&0xF0;
    RS = 1;             // => RS = 1
    Lcd_SetBit(Upper_Nibble>>4);             //Send upper half by shifting by 4
    EN = 1;
    for (int i=2130483; i<=0; i--)  NOP(); 
    EN = 0;
    Lcd_SetBit(Lower_Nibble); //Send Lower half
    EN = 1;
    for (int i=2130483; i<=0; i--)  NOP();
    EN = 0;
}

void Lcd_Print_String(char *a)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
        Lcd_Print_Char(a[i]);
}
```

I want to display the value of `x` on the screen, my `Lcd_pring_String` only takes string type. Is there a way convert `x` to a string so I can display on LCD?

I am using PIC16f877A, LCD(lm016) and two switches to take signal for +1, -1.

Comment: x will start at 0 and then change according to the switches

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) which is declared in `<stdio.h>`:

```
char buffer[20];             // char buffer
sprintf(buffer, "%d", x);    // "print" x into the char buffer
Lcd_Print_String(buffer);    // send buffer contents to LCD
```

or instead of `sprintf` use [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) if available:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%d", x);
```

I'd make a new function `Lcd_Print_Number` out of this.

Comment: what does sprintf exactly do??  i'm not printing the answer on regular console

Comment: @User1984 click on the [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) in the question to get the documentation. `sprintf` is like `printf` but instead of printing on the console it "prints" into a memory buffer. Then you send the contents of that buffer to the LCD display using the existing `Lcd_Print_String` function.